# Ошибка в создании окна при помощи winapi

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

Мучаюсь с шаблоном WinApi.
в ссp файле у меня:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "EDITOR.h"

#include "Windows.h"

EDITOR::EDITOR(
        LPCWSTR _lpWindowName, HINSTANCE _hInst, int _nCmdShow,
        LRESULT (WINAPI *_pWndProc)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM),
        int _nShowOpt,
        LPCTSTR _lpMenuName, DWORD _dwWindowStyle,
        int _x, int _y, int _nWidth, int _nHeight,
        UINT _uClassStyle, HWND _hParent) 
{
    lpWindowName    = _lpWindowName;
    hInst           = _hInst;
    nCmdShow        = _nCmdShow;
    pWndProc        = _pWndProc;

    nShowOpt        = _nShowOpt;
    lpMenuName      = _lpMenuName;
    dwWindowStyle   = _dwWindowStyle;
    x               = _x;
    y               = _y;
    nWidth          = _nWidth;
    nHeight         = _nHeight;
    uClassStyle     = _uClassStyle;
    hParent         = _hParent;

    InitWndClass("My Own Class");
    RegisterWndClass("My Own Class");
    CreateWnd("My Own Class");
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nShowOpt);
}

void EDITOR::InitWndClass(LPCSTR szClassName) { 
     wc.cbSize        = sizeof(wc);      
     wc.style         = uClassStyle;
     wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
     wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
     wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
     wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
     wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
     wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
     wc.lpszMenuName  = lpMenuName;
     wc.hInstance     = hInst;
     wc.lpfnWndProc   = pWndProc;
     wc.lpszClassName = L"szClassName";
}

bool EDITOR::RegisterWndClass(LPCSTR szClassName) {
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        char textMsg[] = "Cannot register class: ";
        MessageBox(NULL, LPCWSTR(textMsg), LPCWSTR("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

bool EDITOR::CreateWnd(LPCSTR szClassName) {
    lpWindowName = L"Текстовый редактор";
    hWnd = CreateWindow(
         szClassName, LPCWSTR(lpWindowName), dwWindowStyle, x, y, 600, 350,
         hParent, (HMENU)NULL, hInst, NULL);
    if (!hWnd) {
        char textMsg[] = "Cannot create window: ";
        MessageBox(NULL, LPCWSTR(textMsg), L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
в h. файле у меня
    #pragma once
class EDITOR
{
public:
    EDITOR(
        LPCWSTR _lpWindowName, HINSTANCE _hInst, int _nCmdShow,
        LRESULT (WINAPI *pWndProc)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM) = NULL,

        int _nShowOpt        = SW_SHOW,
        LPCTSTR _lpMenuName  = NULL,
        DWORD _dwWindowStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        int _x      = CW_USEDEFAULT, int _y       = 0, 
        int _nWidth = CW_USEDEFAULT, int _nHeight = 0,
        UINT _uClassStyle = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
        HWND _hParent     = NULL );


public:

    void InitWndClass(LPCSTR szClassName);    
    bool RegisterWndClass(LPCSTR szClassName); 
    bool CreateWnd(LPCSTR szClassName);        

protected:
    LPCWSTR lpWindowName;   
    HINSTANCE hInst;
    int nCmdShow;           
    LPCTSTR lpMenuName;     
    DWORD dwWindowStyle;    
    int x, y;               
    int nWidth, nHeight;    
    UINT uClassStyle; 
    HWND hParent; 
    LRESULT (WINAPI *pWndProc)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM);
    LRESULT (WINAPI *pWndProc2)(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM) ;
    int nShowOpt;           

protected:
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
};"
```

Ошибка возникает в :

> Ошибка    1   error C2664: CreateWindowExW: невозможно преобразовать параметр 2 из "LPCSTR" в "LPCWSTR"

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Самое интересное, что в .h файле я уже заменил тип этой переменной на "LPCWSTR lpWindowName;", но он всё равно пишет ошибку, что она LPCSTR... Из за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 3):

Поменял ли ты при этом в исходнике (*.cpp) тип переменной?

```
bool EDITOR::CreateWnd(LPCSTR szClassName) {
```

И в конструкторе `EDITOR` ты передаешь `const char*` (LPCSTR), вместо `const wchar_t*` (LPCWSTR)

```
CreateWnd("My Own Class");
```

Вместо

```
CreateWnd(L"My Own Class");
```

Тут такая фигня. Если ты в настройках проекта указываешь Unicode, то (автоматически) объявляется макрос UNICODE, благодаря которому остальные макросы резолвятся в Unicode-версию типов и функций (иначе - в ANSI-версию). Например, у тебя: макрос CreateWindow, становится функцией CreateWindowExW. Потому уж определись, либо везде независимые от макроса UNICODE типы LPCSTR (const char*, это ANSI), либо LPCWSTR (const wchar_t*, это корявый Unicode), либо макросы _T("Some text") и LPCTSTR (const TCHAR*) как тип, которые будут чем нужно, в зависимости от настроек проекта (макроса UNICODE).

Answer (score 1):

Короче. Рекомендую или использовать все строковые переменные как `LPCTSTR` и правильно задать кодировку проекта (как сказал [@V-2142](/users/16817/v-2142)), или сделать **все** строковые константы [относящиеся к WinAPI] `LPCWSTR`.

В данном случае, мне кажется, гадит переменная `LPCSTR szClassName` - она как раз и будет вторым параметром ф-ции `LPCSTR szClassName` [судя по документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в кодировке. Если работаешь в VS, то alt+F7 > Свойства конфигурации > общие > набор символов измени на многобайтовую.